# Do I need a web server or just a database?

Tags: android, database, web, server

I'm new to webservices or databases on the web at all (I've used local databases). I'm developing an Android app based on google maps that needs to access my DB to save/request markers and it needs to access that database from thousands of devices (or I hope so).

Do I need a web server for this so the application on the web can manage the database operations? or can I just call the database from every device? I guess the later is quite unsecure, but I really don't know anything about this matter.

Also, for the answer, should I use Amazon Web Services or Google App Engine? I've read that Google App Engine is easier to deploy, but I don't know about my needs on this application.

**EDIT 1:** My app users need to save markers in the database. If Alice saves a marker in New York, Bob needs to see that marker too. Markers are not personal, they are global. Because of this, every user needs to access the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems to me that you need a database that saves the markers latitude and longitudinal values. This can be done in different ways as you probably figured out.

However I recommend you to look up **Google's own** **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)** which has the following:

[image: Firebase structure]

I recently started with their realtime database and it is really easy to get into plus they have a **great Android integration**. Another great plus is that it is free and I'm not talking about a trial, it is traffic-based.

Getting started with Firebase for Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Samples for Android:https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#android

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I just the database and then I access it from my Android app? I don't need any logic (web server)? Sorry but I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: It's ok! You should ask questions and there is no shame to that.

Firebase is basically an online tool. To simplify a tedious process of implementing databases and setting up users etc. Firebase has all that! You can authenticate users in very simple steps, and everything is through Google's own web server. So all you need to do is setup your Google developer account and voila!, cookies for everyone

Comment: Also I'm guessing the user only interacts with the application and your app needs to save the user information somewhere?

Comment: Ye, I understand how Firebase works. The problem is what Vickyexpert said in the next answer. Every user of my app would have my Google developers acc/pass in the app, isn't it? or that's my understanding.

Comment: Checkout Firebase's Authentication. You can create account for users to use your app. Also by using Authentication, you can restrict access the Firebase Database.

Comment: Ok, I think I got how Firebase works with the authentication. The problem is, that I need to save the markers for EVERYONE. Ill clarify this on my original post. Because of this, can every user access the Firebase with their own google acc?

Comment: Yes you can archive this as well. Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/`)

Comment: @J.Ron Your app is pushing the data. You can restrict the database to the point that only your app is allowed to push data into the database and not a specific user. With that in mind you avoid setting up user accounts if you [don't need it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Seems like Firebase is quite intuitive and easy to implement, gonna give it a try. Will mark your answer for the moment. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge and understanding of Android, first of all you will not be able to connect server database directly in android app, and if you can do it then check below drawbacks of it.

There are a number of reasons.

**1. Security**- If the user has direct access, they can get anything from your database. Plus they will have a password into your database. As a result, if the SQL server you are using has a flaw, then they can exploit it. Also, if your permissions are set up wrong, the could wipe your database.

**2. Speed**- If the users frequently use large queries, then it can bog down your system quickly and needlessly. If you go through a web interface, you can throttle it.

**3. Accessibility**- Web queries are supported by almost everything. It requires special clients to access SQL databases directly.

So, you should not access directly, instead of that you should develop web api and access it.

Hope ypu got the point what I want to say

Comment: So, you propose to, for example, use Google App Engine instead of only a  database? although I don't need web interface, only the logic that will access the database. App users then call my web api to access the database and they got no clues of my Google acc/pass?

Comment: Yes, see web interface and Web API both are different things, web interface provides a site in browser to manage and handle for users, when Web APIs are not visible to end users and it will only worked in background without using any kind of UI and manage the request and response for server and database.